# prolog: predicate which is true if two lists are the same without a specific element

Tags: prolog

I want to write a predicate `withoutElement(A,Lf,Lg)` in prolog which is true if list `Lg` is the same as list `Lf` without element `A`.

for example:

```
withoutElement(a,[a,b,c,d],[a,b,c,d]).
```

= False

and

```
withoutElement(a,[a,b,c,d],[b,c,d]).
```

= True

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Ok, good plan. What's the question?

Comment: You may want to consider also `withoutElement(X,[a,b,c,d],R)`

Comment: What should he result of `withoutElement(a, [a,a,b,c,a], L).` result in? Should `withoutElement(a, [a,a,b,c,a], [b,c])` succeed or fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a recursive definition:

```
without_element(A, [A|Lg], Lg).    % True if element A is 
                                   % head of Lf and the tail (Lg)
                                   % is the same.
without_element(A, Lf, [A|Lf]).    % If you want to check the other way round
without_element(A, [H|T1], [H|T2]) :- without_element(A, T1, T2).  % ↵
% Check first elements are the same, continue checking rest of lists.
```

Comment: it looks almost good but it only works if the element A is the first element (list head) of Lf. Is it possible that this solution also works if A is at any position in list Lf? THX in advance!

Comment: It works no matter where A is because it is recursive. It exits the recursion when it finds A at the head. It checks Lf and Lg are equal until it finds A. It checks the rest of Lf and Lg are equal after it has found A. Try it with some examples.

Comment: To stop it looking for multiple solutions, change the first to clauses to have the bodies `true, !.`, e.g. `without_element(A, [A|Lg], Lg) :- true, !.`